# Syntax error: Unexpected token < (less than)

Tags: xml, opencart

Why would I get an error about an unexpected token `<`?

I just started to write my first ocmode extension.   The idea is to display product code in categories. Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<modification>
    <name>Articles</name>
    <code>article</code>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <vqmver></vqmver>
    <author>Bogdan</author>
    <date>2016.01.31</date>

    <file path="catalog/controller/product/category.php">
        <operation>
            <search><'name'        => $result['name'],></search>
            <add position="before">< 'model'        => $result['model'],></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <file path="catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/category.tpl">
        <operation>
            <search><<p><?php echo $product['description']; ?></p>></search>
            <add position="before"><<h3>product code:</h3>    <h4><?php echo $product['model']; ?></h4>></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```

But when I try to upload it site gives the dialog box with this error. What am I doing wrong? Currently I use last version of opencart.

deleted the second file with a view here is updated code
error is still the same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<modification>
    <name>Articles</name>
    <code>article</code>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <vqmver></vqmver>
    <author>Bogdan</author>
    <date>2016.01.31</date>

    <file path="catalog/controller/product/category.php">
        <operation>
            <search><'name'        => $result['name'],></search>
            <add position="before">< 'model'        => $result['model'],></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common reasons why a `<` would be an unexpected token include:

1. **A program is expecting XML**, and `<` appears in the *content*.

   **Resolution**:  Use `&lt;` to represent `<` as itself; otherwise, it's expected to be a part of the *markup*.
2. **A program is *not* expecting XML**, and `<` appears in the *markup*.

   **Resolution**: Don't send XML when a program is expecting another format, or communicate properly that XML should be expected or is required.

   a. If your AJAX call expects XML, use `dataType: 'xml'`; JSON, `dataType: 'json'`.

   b. If callers are expecting JSON, don't return HTML-formated 404 File Not Found responses.

Comment: `search` and `add` elements still have content with `<`, not `&lt`.